# CMAKE link shared library that has version information

Tags: makefile, cmake

I upgraded ORACLE and the library no is called libocci.so.12.1.

When I compile via (cmake.. and make) the linking fails. It does not find libocci.
My previous version of occi was named libocci.so.

How to I resolve this without creating soft links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like `FindOcci.cmake` module then it should successfully locate the library when you re-run CMake. If it doesn't, take a look at its source and fix it.

Alternatively, if you just use the hardcoded library name like `target_link_libraries(myapp occi)`, you need to search for it first. Take a look at [find_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library) command.